# Microsoft Graph API get multiple B2C user via email address

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the use case to query multiple b2c user from the microsoft graph api to get the display name and get the information about the last login. I am aware that the last login is just available via the beta route.

I am using the microsoft graph api beta client and try to get a user via an email address.

My b2c users do not have any mail or otherMail values, only information about the email is placed in the identities list.

```
var result = await client.Users
.Request()
.Select(e => new
{
    e.DisplayName,
    e.UserType,
    e.OtherMails,
    e.UserPrincipalName,
    e.Mail,
    e.Identities,
    e.SignInActivity
}).GetAsync();
```

This Call returns all user, so I would have to filter in memory which would be bad.

`.Filter("identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'superUser@mail.com')")`

This filter function returns exactly one specific user, but I wasn't able to query multiple users via a single request. Something like
`.Filter("identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'superUser@mail.com') or identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'superUser2@mail.com')")`
Return query is to complex an replace the 'eq' with an 'in' returns not supported query, because looks like lambda operators do not support 'in'.

Has someone an idea how to query for e.g. 2 emails addresses with an single request?

Comment: Complex queries on that property is not supported by Graph. Try using batch api where you execute two searches in different requests. Remember this means one more request. See more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Danstan,

with the a batch request it works to get with single request up to 20 accounts at once. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp#simple-batching-example
The API still limited it to 20 request in a single batch request. 'Code: MaximumValueExceeded
Message: Number of batch request steps exceeds the maximum value of 20.'

This makes it possible to query all the data by view requests.

Comment: Hi @Changer, Could you please share the final code that solved your problem? I guess many users have the same problem here, so it would be really useful for us.

Answer (score 1):

I also can provide an rosly pad script were you just have to set your specific values like client id, secret and so on.

```cs
#r "nuget:Microsoft.Graph.Auth/1.0.0-preview.7"
#r "nuget:Microsoft.Graph.Beta/4.28.0-preview"

#r "nuget:RestSharp/107.1.1"
#r "nuget:RestRequest/1.2.0"
#r "nuget:Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/1.6.2"
#r "nuget:Azure.Core/1.22.0"
#r "nuget:Azure.Identity/1.5.0"

using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Linq;
using Azure.Core;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

using System.Net.Http;


var client = await GetGraphApiClient();

var emails = new []{  "email1@example.de","email2@example.de","email3@example.de","email4@example.de","email5@example.de"};

// Build the batch
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

// Using AddBatchRequestStep adds each request as a step
foreach (var element in emails)
{
    var userRequest2 = client.Users
        .Request()
        .Select(e => new
        {
            e.DisplayName,
            e.UserType,
            e.OtherMails,
            e.UserPrincipalName,
            e.Mail,
            e.Identities,
            e.SignInActivity // just provided in the Microsoft.Graph.Beta package 
        })
    .Filter($"identities/any(id:id/issuer eq ' ' and id/issuerAssignedId eq '{element}')");
    batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(userRequest2);
}

var returnedResponse = await client.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

try
{
    var user = await returnedResponse
        .GetResponsesAsync();
    user.Dump();
}
catch (ServiceException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to get user: {ex.Error.Message}");
}

private static async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphApiClient()
{
    var clientId = "<Client-Id-Of-your-app-with-graph-access>";
    var secret = "<Client-Secret-Of-your-app-with-graph-access>";
    var tenant = "<tenant-id>";

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "AuditLog.Read.All", "User.Read.All" };

    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenant)
            .WithClientSecret(secret)
            .Build();
    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

var serviceToken = await authProvider.ClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

    return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

}
```